# google-apps-script ContactsApp.getContact(email) migration to People API

Tags: google-apps-script

How to write this simple line :

`ContactsApp.getContact(email);`

with the new People API ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Workflow:

- Use [people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) to get the list of contacts of the requested user, specified via `resourceName` (`people/me` refers to the authenticated user).
- Find the contact who has an email address like the one you are looking for.

#### Important notes:

- Naturally, you won't get exactly the same information as in `ContactsApp.getContact`, since they are different API's. In this case, you'll get an instance of the [Person resource](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people).
- You can choose which information should be populated on the retrieved person, using `personFields` (see the list of available fields [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#query-parameters)). Request multiple fields by providing a comma-separated string of fields (in the example below, `emailAddresses` and `biographies` are requested).

#### Code sample:

```
function getPerson(email) {
  const resourceName = "people/me";
  const optionalArgs = {
    personFields: 'emailAddresses,biographies' // Add the person fields you want
  }
  const response = People.People.Connections.list(resourceName, optionalArgs);
  const { connections } = response;
  const person = connections.find(connection => {
    return connection["emailAddresses"] && connection["emailAddresses"].some(emailAddress => emailAddress["value"] === email);
  });
  return person;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this solution.

Comment: It works but so complicated comparing to the old API...
Thank you.